# Processing time in java

Tags: java, swing, time, jpanel, simpledateformat

I'm trying to make a java application that popup message every 2 hours but for testting purpose I've shrinked the time to 2 minutes. the problem is that I'm not getting the Jpanel to popup whenever the while condition is evaluated to false.. here is the code I'm using:

```
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
     Calendar cal2;
    SimpleDateFormat ST = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
    SimpleDateFormat CT;
    String x = ST.format(cal.getTime());
    int StartT = Integer.parseInt(x);
    StartT= StartT+2;
    int CurrentT;
    //System.out.println( x2 );
    do{
         cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        CT = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
        String y = ST.format(cal2.getTime());
         CurrentT = Integer.parseInt(y);
    }while(CurrentT < StartT );
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "MSG_Text..");
```

Comment: Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't re-invent the wheel use a [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class for it and schedule the task at a fixed rate...

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     Timer t = new Timer("testTimer", true);
     t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         System.out.println("hello world");
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "MSG_Text..");     
     }
     }, 0L, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(30)); //run will be invoked every 30 seconds 
     while (true) {
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get an error says that Timer constructor doesnt accept a string and a boolean value

Comment: then you are using the wrong timer... you need to use the java.util.Timer;

Comment: *"then you are using the wrong timer..."* So are you. Using the `javax.swing.Timer` ensures that any calls to GUI components are done on the EDT.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for ! thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put a `System.out` after your do-while loop, in order to see if your code finishes your loop at all?

---

This Calendar / SimpleDateFormat / foo stuff really hurts my eyes!

1. It's active waiting / busy waiting. It costs lot's of CPU power. Busy waiting is a main reason for climate change! Don't do that! ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting )
2. Use `Thread.sleep`. 1 line, much shorter, easier, less error prone, costs nearly no CPU power.

---

Java provides a **huge** framework for nearly everything. There are APIs for sleeping / waiting / time computations / etc.

Don't build your own. There were lot's of people designing the JDK, checking the code for errors, made it easy to use.

Comment: I agree: it really hurts

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Timertask which is better than this you own function
Also it will not be executed anymore when it will reach to 2359
the last minute of day.

Answer (score -1):

Have you heard about:
[Thread#sleep(long millis)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)

```
Thread.sleep(2 * 60 * 1000)
```

This is far better than active waiting (Because it takes less CPU power).

If you need to execute only at some special time like 10:15:00.000 you can adjust this using

```
long timeToWait = nextExecutionTIme - System.currentTimeMillis() + 1;
Thread.sleep(timeToWait);
```

EDIT:

```
while (true) {
    Thread.sleep(2 * 60 * 1000)
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "MSG_Text..");
}
```

Comment: then how can I popup the JPanel ?